# Redireccionar a otra página

Tags: php, grocery-crud

Tengo un CRUD en el cual quiero que después que el usuario añada una nueva fila me redireccione a otro CRUD que tengo y a su vez me muestre un mensaje, he estado tratando de utilizar `callback_after_insert()` pero no he podido lograr que me envíe al otro CRUD. Esta es la función del CRUD de donde quiero que me envíe al otro.

```
public function foo(){
    validateSession(self::LOGIN_TYPE, TRUE);

    $data['title'] = 'foo';
    $data['breadcrumb'] = 'foo';
    $data['icon'] = 'glyphicon glyphicon-th-list';

    //CRUD
    try{

        $settings = array(
            'table' => 'foo',
            'subject' => 'foo',
            'columns' => array("id",'nombre','descripcion','tipo'),
            'alias' => array(
                'id' => '#',
                'nombre' => 'Nombre',
                'descripcion' => 'Descripción',
                'tipo' => 'Tipo',
            ),
            //'fields' => array('nombre','descripcion','tipo'),
        );

        $crud = CRUD::Create($settings);

        //field types

        $crud->unset_texteditor('descripcion');
        $crud->field_type('tipo','dropdown',
            array('FOO' => 'FOO', 'FOO2' => 'FOO2'));


        //Output
        $data['crud'] = $crud->render();

    } catch (Exception $e){

    }//try-catch

    $this->load->view('htdocs/header.php', $data);
    $this->load->view('htdocs/crud-view.php', $data);
    $this->load->view('htdocs/footer.php', $data);

}//end
```

Answer (score 0):

Bueno he tratado me he encontrado en otro foro algo que me ha ayudado y es utilizar `set_lang_string()` a continuación muestro como se utilizó:

```
$crud->set_lang_string('insert_success_message',
                '<script type="text/javascript">
                window.location = "'.site_url(strtolower(__CLASS__).'/CRUD al que se desea redireccionaar').'";
                </script>');
```